# Codeigniter pagination per_page by array

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am new at codeigniter pagination. I tried to config per_page by array value. This is example I tried:

```
    //dynamic limit
    $limit = array(10, 20, 30);
    if (!is_null($offset)) {
        $offset = $this->uri->segment(2);
    }
    $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('product');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->mod_product->count_item();
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $config['num_links'] = 10;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['items'] = $this->mod_product->get_product($limit, $offset);

    $this->load->view("product", $data);
```

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by "pagination limited by array". What does your code actually produce and what do you want it to produce?

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: Why the array needed? Per page should be a single number.

Answer (score 1):

Please first include library.

```
public function __construct() {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->helper("url");
        $this->load->model("Countries");
        $this->load->library("pagination");
    }

    public function example1() {
        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "welcome/example1";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->Countries->record_count();
        $config["per_page"] = 20;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data["results"] = $this->Countries->
            fetch_countries($config["per_page"], $page);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->load->view("example1", $data);
    }
```